# Is this a correct combination of MOSFETs for an H-bridge design? If its wrong, what should I do?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, power-electronics

[image: h bridge]

Vdc is +12v and PWM signal will be 10 kHz. M+ and M- will connect to motor. I will apply PWM from the upper MOSFETs and apply a logic signal to the lower MOSFETs.

Comment: High-side NMOSFETs are backwards and will short. Note the body diode in the MOSFET symbol. It's not there for show. After you correct that error, look up "high-side floating gate driver" to see the next problem. You don't want your high side MOSFETs to be *source followers* which is what they will be if you control the gate voltage the same way as the low-side MOSFETs.

Comment: Welcome! Impossible to tell. What’s your voltage? How fast are you switching?

Comment: Im planning to switch with 10khz

Comment: Please edit that information along with Vcc voltage into your question. Have you tried to simulate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is this a correct combination of MOSFETs for an H-bridge design?*

- No it's wrong irrespective of whether Vdc is positive or negative.
- If Vdc is in fact a negative DC supply then the lower P-channel MOSFETs would need source and drain pins swapping (as well as the bias resistors and associated resistor.
- If Vdc is a positive supply then do the above then swap the P-channel MOSFET positions with the N-channel MOSFET positions and re-present here for checking.
- You appear to be using dual MOSFET packages but have got things muddled.

<sub>A H-bridge circuit is fundamentally dependent on the MOSFET drivers and, in the absence of those details in the schematic, it's impossible to say if other errors are present. Regarding the load it feeds, without those details it's impossible to say if the devices chosen (when corrected in their positions) are substantial enough. This also includes any heatsinking they require.</sub>

> *I will apply PWM from the upper MOSFETs and apply a logic signal to
> the lower MOSFETs.*

It remains to be seen whether this is the best way to drive the circuit.

> *If its wrong, what should I do?*

That's completely up to you.

Answer (score 2):

A schematic diagram is always the easiest way to illustrate the comments. Basically, you have the choice between two main arrangements for a full-bridge:

1. if you go high voltage, then most of the circuits are using four N-channel MOSFETs which require either fully-isolated high-side drivers or bootstrapped drivers like the venerable IR2110 to cite an old reference (see [here](http://tahmidmc.blogspot.com/2013/01/using-high-low-side-driver-ir2110-with.html) for more details). You need this bootstrapped technique because the source of the upper transistors is not tied to a fixed potential.

[image]

Please note that the diodes in the represented circuit are the body diodes of the transistors and offer a path for *freewheel* operations.

2. if you are in the low-voltage arena, then you can perhaps identify suitable P-channel transistors whose source will connect to the fixed upper-rail dc-voltage and thus allow a direct ground-referenced control. This solution is usually restrained to low-voltage applications as P-channel are less performant \$r_{DS(on)}\$-wise in high-voltage than their N counterparts and are more expensive.

[image]

In this case, the low-side MOSFETs are easily controlled by a ground-referenced signal (0-12 V for instance) but you need to swing up to \$V_{bus}\$ for blocking the P-channel transistors. And when the control signal goes low for turning them on, you have to make sure the \$V_{GS}\$ remains within their max rating, usually below 20 V. So it looks simpler to control on the paper but still requires careful drive. I found this other [article](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/how-to-implement-p-channel-mosfet-in-h-bridge-applications/) well documented too.